# Laravel 6.9 belongsToMany Relationships return one collection

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I have Many To Many Relationships. I have three tables:

```
posts
posts_tag
tags
```

Table "posts" have standart fields.

The structure of the table "posts_tag":

```
Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');

    $table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
});
```

The structure of the table "tags":

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The relationship is defined in the model:

```
 class Tag extends Model
{

        public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

I call the method `$tag->posts`:

```
public function getPostsByTag($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id);

    dd($tag->posts);

}
```

I get only one array:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#571 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}
```

[screenshot database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gxsa.png)

I will be grateful for any help friends! If you're sorry for my English, I'm in the process of learning!

Comment: I apologize not so wrote, so as You wrote, so and there is!

Comment: what is the value of `$id`? and the pivot table is `posts_tag` or `post_tag`?

Comment: This will be the id by which I will filter!  and the pivot table is "posts_tag"!

Comment: which certain `$id` do you send to `getPostsByTag`? I mean value.

Comment: I have route:  `Route::get('/tag/{id?}', 'PostController@getPostsByTag')->name('blog.getPostsByTag');`

Comment: ok, but I ask about a certain value. Example /tag/10 - value is 10. What is your value for provided output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your Tag modal**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

**In your Post modal**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class,'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
public function getPostsByTag($id)
{
    $tag = Post::with('tags')->find($id);
    dd($tag);
}
```

Comment: `App\Models\Post {#573 ▼
  #fillable: array:28 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "tags" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#577 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}`  - I still get one array

Comment: Thank you good man! The problem was here: 

`class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class,'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
}` it was ` return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class,'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');`

Comment: Yes to get all the posts for a certain tag you need it to be like this: `class Tag extends Model { public function posts() { return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id'); } }` - 'tag_id', 'post_id' were also on the contrary –